# Splatting without assigning hash or array to a variable

Tags: powershell, parameter-passing

I have a command that returns a hash table. Like this one, for example:

```
function Get-TestArgs() { return @{a=1;b=2;c=3} }
```

And I'd like to use its return value as the arguments for my other function:

```
function Test($a, $b, $c) {
    Write-Host 'A' $a
    Write-Host 'B' $b
    Write-Host 'C' $c
}
```

This is possible with PowerShell's [splatting](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj672955.aspx) feature:

```
$testargs = @{a=1;b=2;c=3}
Test @testargs
```

The problem is I don't want to assign the hash to an intermediate variable.

Something along these lines is what I have in mind:

```
Test (some splat syntax)(Get-TestArgs)
```

Obviously, this wouldn't work, since it just creates an array containing the hash and passes that:

```
Test @(Get-TestArgs)
```

Is there a way to achieve this?

#### Reason I care

I am writing instructions that will be executed manually. These instructions will call out to scripts, but there is still some manual intervention to be done between calls. So I'd like to minimize the commands to reduce the risk of something going wrong, like a variable being leftover from other commands or a typo.

Comment: I think the desired result can be achieved with an array. However, the question was specifically "without array" due to manual execution.

Answer (score 7):

I don't think it's possible to use splatting without a variable. But there are few workarounds to achieve what you're looking for.

1. Write a wrapper function that would take a hashtable and invoke the 'real' function. If you wanted to call the function directly, without `Get-TestArgs`, you would use `TestInner`.

   ```
   function Get-TestArgs() { return @{a=1;b=2;c=3} }

   function TestInner ($a, $b, $c)
   {
       write-host "a=" $a
       write-host "b=" $b
       write-host "c=" $c
   }

   function Test ($hash) {
       return TestInner @hash
   }

   Test (Get-TestArgs)
   TestInner 1 2 3
   ```
2. Design your functions so that each takes a hashtable as the only parameter - it's a simplified version of 1. It looks a little ugly - you cannot determine the required parameters to `Test` just by looking at its declaration.

   ```
   function Test ($hash)
   {
       write-host "a=" $hash.a
       write-host "b=" $hash.b
       write-host "c=" $hash.c
   }

   Test (Get-TestArgs)
   ```
3. Use the approach from 2., but create a new type for the function parameter, to be a little more "type safe":

   ```
   add-type -TypeDefinition @"
       public class TestArg {
           public int a = 0;
           public int b = 0;
           public int c = 0;
       }
   "@

   function Get-TestArgs() { return new-object -type "TestArg" -Property @{a=1;b=2;c=3} }

   function Test ([TestArg] $o)
   {
       write-host "a=" $o.a
       write-host "b=" $o.b
       write-host "c=" $o.c
   }


   Test (Get-TestArgs)
   ```
4. Take advantage of parameter sets and pipelines. This is similar to writing a wrapper, but the target function is also the wrapper - depending on the parameter set, it will either execute normally or use splatting to invoke itself again, but with different parameter set.

   ```
   function Test {
   param(
       [Parameter(ParameterSetName="set1",Position=0)][int]$a, 
       [Parameter(ParameterSetName="set1",Position=1)][int]$b, 
       [Parameter(ParameterSetName="set1",Position=2)][int]$c, 
       [Parameter(ParameterSetName="pipeline",ValueFromPipeLine=$true,Position=0)][Hashtable]$obj
   )

       if ($obj -ne $null) { return Test @obj }

       write-host "a=" $a
       write-host "b=" $c
       write-host "c=" $c

   }

   Test (Get-TestArgs)
   Get-TestArgs | Test        
   Test 1 2 3
   ```

Depending on how many functions you need to create and how are you intend to invoke them, you could choose one of these solutions. Personally, the last one seems the most elegant choice to me. And I would go with pipes: `Get-TestArgs | Test` looks more natural in PowerShell than `Test (Get-TestArgs)`. 
For example, many of [Azure PowerShell commands](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn168976(v=nav.70).aspx) are designed to work that way.

Comment: I also like option 4 - the pipeline.

Answer (score 4):

I'm fairly certain this can't be done with splatting because:

> [[Splatting] says, “Take whatever characters come next and assume they’re a
>   variable name. Assume that the variable contains a hashtable, and that
>   the keys are parameter names. Expand those out, and feed the values
>   from the hashtable to those parameters.” That may sound like a
>   long-winded explanation, but that’s what’s happening.](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/gg675931.aspx)

I really think the best you'll be able to do is:

```
function Test() {
    param($a, $b, $c)
    Write-Host 'A' $a
    Write-Host 'B' $b
    Write-Host 'C' $c
}

function Get-TestArgs() { @(1,2,3) }

$p = Get-TestArgs; Test @p
```

Answer (score 1):

This can easily be accomplished without a (user-defined) variable by piping your hashtable to ForEach-Object (alias %) and splatting the automatic variable $PSItem (alias $_).

```
Get-TestArgs | ForEach-Object {Test @PSItem}
Get-TestArgs | % {Test @_}
```

which both return:

```
A 1
B 2
C 3
```

Comment: Nice, but not as clean as I would prefer :/

Comment: @jpmc26 Perhaps you could choose this as the answer to your question?

Answer (score 0):

I saw that this post dates from more than 3 years ago, but just in case someone else (like me) comes across this post, the following solution works and has been tested in a powershell 5 and 3 console (powershell.exe -Version 3)

Use a delegate and invoke it:

```
&{ param($hashtable) &functionToRun @hashtable} (functionReturningHashTable)
```

Based on the code originally published:

```
function Get-TestArgs() { return @{a=1;b=2;c=3} }

function Test($a, $b, $c) {
    Write-Host 'A' $a
    Write-Host 'B' $b
    Write-Host 'C' $c
}

&{ param($hashtable) &Test @hashtable} (Get-TestArgs)
```

Returns:
    
    `A 1
    B 2
    C 3`

You can even put all the commands you want in the last parentheses.

Assuming you have 3 files a, b, c in your current directory (if not use the following code to create them):

```
     'a','b','c' | % { New-Item -Path $_ -ItemType File }

     Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name
     ----                -------------         ------ ----
     -a----       15/12/2019     14:34              0 a
     -a----       15/12/2019     14:34              0 b
     -a----       15/12/2019     14:34              0 c
```

Then you can do the following command :

```
&{ param([hashtable]$hashtable) &Test @hashtable} (gci | group -AsHashTable -Property Name)
```

It returns:

```
     A a
     B b
     C c
```

Use following code to delete created files:

```
     'a','b','c' | % { Remove-Item -Path $_ }
```

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
&{param($p=(Get-TestArgs)) Test @p}
```

or this:

```
Get-TestArgs | &{param([Parameter(ValueFromPipeline)]$p) Test @p}
```

`$p` will not be bound to anything because these were done within call operator `&` script blocks.